# Bold text in a comment [within italics] doesn't work on the mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting, mobile

I've posted a comment to this question: "[hinschauen meaning](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/8076/3498)".

It should look like this:

> The first one means "I fell in love at first sight." The second on the other hand doesn't make sense. Are you sure it says: "*Ich hätte **mich** zweimal hinschauen sollen.*"?

Where the word `mich` is in italics and bold. But on the mobile site it doesn't show the bold part, only the italics:

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed and will be deployed in the next build out.